# Thonny crashing…why?

Tags: python, crash

I’m an amateur, but I’ve used raspberry pi’s and have code running on them 24/7 for several years now with no issues.

My latest home automation project has a (Python) raspberry pi outdoors (in North Carolina, it’s in the 90’s in summer) in a green waterproof “sockit box” from Amazon. This code has run without issue for a few months earlier in the year, but in the past few months I’ve noticed it not running numerous times. My first thought was it’s getting too hot in the waterproof box and the pi is shutting down or failing, but when I check on it, Thonny itself is closed. Next, I thought it was power outages but the folders or text files I have open are still open on the desktop, so it must not be raspberry pi itself restarting.

I understand that posting code is generally the way to go for asking questions, but my code is rather lengthy, amateur-messy, and since thonny itself is closing or crashing, I’m not sure that it’s my code causing this. I don’t expect people to read through my entire code for this, but I will post it if everyone deems that necessary to assist me on this topic. Although I’m not sure how to post that much code here. Also, I recently reformatted the SD card with a fresh install and I have still had the same issue.

This is my first time reading sensors that require using an interrupt, so that’s one new variable. I’m also reading and writing text files on the pi for the first time. Also, the internet connection is spotty, and I am uploading data to web. While I wouldn’t expect that to cause thonny to crash, is there some reason I’m not thinking of that could cause that?

Are there any common reasons that thonny itself would crash while running code that I could check? I’m also considering trying a different IDE to see if that can isolate the issue.

Comment: Thonny is a code editor / IDE. You can use it for editing and debugging. It's not meant to run your code in 'production'. So first thing to do is to run your code from the command line. With a bit of luck you will see an error message when your script crashes.

Comment: From your (I'm afraid largely irrelevant) discourse, I understand that your IDE sometimes crashes. Not the Pi. The watertight sealing is also (as you determined) not an issue. There are a number of reasons why the IDE might crash; it may not be your code, but googling for "Thonny IDE crash" gave me quite a number of other reasons.

Comment: Have you looked in the system logs for messages about errors or unexpected events? Are you certain that your Pi didn't just reboot, rather than assuming that Thonny crashed?

Comment: I searched for Thonny crash (without IDE) and didn’t find anything that seemed to be helpful. I tried to only post enough information to describe the circumstances, but it seems to get long winded. Being amateur, I know nothing about system logs.

Comment: I have a feeling you are getting lost or over time in your ISR (Interrupt Service Routine). The best way to do them is set a software flag, clear it if needed and get out. Your main code should check the flag and take appropriate action. KF6THi

Comment: Gil, I'm brand new to interrupts and my interrupt code is just a copy and pasted code section from a tutorial somewhere, where I just wrote the callback for my use case. I'm interested to learn more about the method you suggest (which I don't understand). I don't know how to get code to format correctly here. My current interrupt code is below.

Comment: ````def signal_handler(sig, frame):  
    GPIO.cleanup()  
    sys.exit(0)  
      
if True: #interrupt code, keep it always going to detect an interrupt  
    GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSensorPin, GPIO.FALLING,   
            callback=PulseDetectedCallback, bouncetime=500)  
      
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)  
    #signal.pause()````

Comment: Update: I’ve been running the code from command line with no issues for nearly a week now. While this isn’t definite proof of the issue being resolved (it has run for months without issues previously, but not recently), it seems like a good start. I am also going to look into different/better interrupt methods.